# Pointer obejct function call without instantiating it

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I don't understand how does following code called f() function successfully. As object b is not instantiated using new keyword.
Please help and Thanks in advance for answers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{ public:
    void f(){cout<<"f";}
};

int main()
{
    A *b;
    delete b;
    b->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete b;` is already wrong, since at this point `b` is not even initialized, let alone pointing at memory allocated with `new`.

Comment: The short answer is that if you want code that is wrong to *consistently not appear to work*, then C and C++ are not viable languages for you.

Comment: In the name of efficiency, C++ assumes the programmer isn't out to shoot themselves in the foot and makes very few checks to ensure the programmer's not doing something foolish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how does following code called f() function successfully.

The program has **undefined behavior** since `b` is not initialized and is also not pointing to memory allocated by `new`.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Auht0Bwch) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kZvfXQ3ULCmzICfa) it crashes.

To solve this make sure that the pointer `b` is initialized and is pointing to memory allocated by `new`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>